# org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Code:

```
List<WebElement> d=driver.findElements(By.className("store-name"));
System.out.println(d.size());
for(WebElement d1:d) {
    System.out.println(d1.getText());
    d1.click();

    WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.id("comp-contact"));
    e.getText();
    System.out.println(e.getText());
    Thread.sleep(500);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
    js.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");
}
```

After executing my above code, It's giving me following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale: either the
element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: It's not clear where you're seeing this issue. But generally speaking you get this error when you find an element, and then the page changes and the element is no longer in the same location with the **html** or **DOM** structure. The general solution is to make sure that you wait for the last thing or two that happens on the page to happen before interacting with elements, and whenever you do something that causes the page to change, you reload the page object or re-find the elements you use after that.

Comment: With the updated formatting, now I think I see what your problem is. The page is refreshing so all of your elements are stale on the second time through the loop. You need to loop on the count of the elements, and re-find the element you want with a counter variable with every iteration. Also, you should be able to go back without using the much overused `JavascriptExecutor`

Comment: it throws while some element get change their properties in page after your click or any other actions. So check that first and take new element according to it.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution, but it should work.
Note that I'm making two assumptions about your test target:  
  1) That the first element you are trying to click is a link, otherwise change the 'a' in the XPath to the appropriate HTML tag for your target element.
  2) The elements in your list do not share the same direct parent, in that case, you could use the XPath: `"//a[@class='store-name']["+i+"]"`

```
List<WebElement> d=driver.findElements(By.className("store-name"));
System.out.println(d.size());
for(int i=1;i<=d.size();i++) {
    WebElement d1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='store-name'])["+i+"]"));
    System.out.println(d1.getText());
    d1.click();

    WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.id("comp-contact"));
    e.getText();
    System.out.println(e.getText());
    Thread.sleep(500);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
    js.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");
}
```

I couldn't think of a good way to loop through the elements without using xpath or rebuilding the list.  If you're against using xpath you could also remake the list and get the relevant element from it:

```
List<WebElement> dLoop=driver.findElements(By.className("store-name"));
WebElement d1 = dLoop.get(i);
```